# LifeCycleOwner in Broadcast reciever

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I am using Android Room to store my application data. After device reboot I need to retrieve them and do some functions. I am using LiveData for getting data from database. But I cannot bind Broadcast Reciever as owner. How should I resolve this problem?

```
public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (context != null) {
            ProductUIRepository mRepository = new ProductUIRepository(context.getApplicationContext());
            mRepository.findAllProducts().observe(this, new android.arch.lifecycle.Observer<List<ProductUI>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable List<ProductUI> productUIS) {
                    NotificationMan.setAlarmForProducts(context, productUIS);

                }
            });
    }
  }
}
```

using "this" makes that applications isn't compiling.

Comment: Did you get this to work? I've run into similar problem

Comment: and nothing yet?